# [Hibernate][JPA] Unknown mappedBy in .. referenced property unknown:

Tags: hibernate

I have an abstract superclass "RessourceMaterielle" and an entity derived class "Vehicule". 
I have a 1 to 1 mapping between the sperclass and another class "Localisation".
The abstract superclass is not represented in the database. I want the mapping between the superclass and the Localisation to be inherited by the derived class, so that Hibernate sees a mapping between Vehicule and Localisation. Is that possible?

Superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class RessourceMaterielle extends ObjetMetier {
    private String nom = null;
    private Localisation localisation = null;

        @Column(name = "`NOM`")
    public String getNom() {
        return this.nom == null ? null : new String(this.nom);
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = new String(nom);
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="`LOCALISATION`")
    public Localisation getLocalisation() {
        return this.localisation == null ? null : this.localisation.clone();
    }

    public void setLocalisation(Localisation localisation) {
        this.localisation = localisation.clone();
    }

    public RessourceMaterielle(){

    }

}
```

Vehicule:

```
@Entity(name = "VEHICULE")
@Table(name = "`VEHICULE`")
public class Vehicule extends RessourceMaterielle {

    public Vehicule() {
    }

}
```

Localisation:

```
@Entity(name = "LOCALISATION")
@Table(name = "`LOCALISATION`")
public class Localisation extends ObjetMetier {
    private double lon = -1111;
    private double lat = -1111;
    private RessourceMaterielle ressourceMaterielle;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "localisation")
    public RessourceMaterielle getRessourceMaterielle() {
        return (RessourceMaterielle) (this.ressourceMaterielle == null ? null : this.ressourceMaterielle.clone());
    }

    public void setRessourceMaterielle(RessourceMaterielle ressourceMaterielle) {
        this.ressourceMaterielle = ressourceMaterielle;
    }

    @Column(name = "`LON`")
    public double getLon() {
        return this.lon;
    }

    public void setLon(double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    @Column(name = "`LAT`")
    public double getLat() {
        return this.lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Localisation() {

    }

    public Localisation(double lon, double lat) {
        this.setLon(lon);
        this.setLat(lat);
    }
}
```

When I run a test that persists a Vehicule into the database I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.organisme.model.localisation.Localisation.ressourceMaterielle, referenced property unknown: com.organisme.model.ressource.RessourceMaterielle.localisation
```

Is there any solution?

Regards.